# How to create a single bundle with CSS and JS files?

Tags: angular, build, web-component, angular-builder

I'm creating web components in Angular by grabbing .js files which include `runtime.js`, `polyfills.js` and `main.js` and concatenating them into single file called **list.js** by using below code

```
const fs = require('fs-extra');
const concat = require('concat');

(async function build() {

    const files = [
        './dist/dls-webcomponents/runtime.js',
        './dist/dls-webcomponents/polyfills.js',
        './dist/dls-webcomponents/main.js'             
    ]

    await fs.ensureDir('elements')

    await concat(files, 'elements/list.js')

})()
```

angular.json

```
"scripts": {
     ...
    "build:elements": "ng build --prod --output-hashing none && node build-helper.js "
  }
```

While generating the production build angular is creating above .js files along with `styles.css` file.

Is there anyway that I can include this styles in above `list.js` file?